# Why are .call and .apply slower than a direct function call in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm curious about [these jsperf results](http://jsperf.com/function-versus-function-call-versus-function-apply). They appear to demonstrate that a direct function call is substantially faster than the same function called with `.call` or `.apply`. (The difference between `.call` and `.apply` surprised me even more.) Could you please explain these results?

Update: [Here is a jsperf](http://jsperf.com/function-versus-function-call-versus-function-apply/2) that someone left that tests .apply without a second array instantiation.

Comment: Well, for one thing, there's at least one more function call involved (the call to ".call()" or ".apply()") ...

Comment: ... and, indeed, it's about half as fast to go through ".call()" or ".apply()", which is about what you'd expect it'd cost to do two function calls instead of just one.

Comment: `.apply` is slower because you're constructing an array as well.

Comment: @Pointy that is a decent empirical explanation, except that [according to Yehuda Katz](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/), `function.call()` and `obj.func()` should be desugared to the same internal invocation of `[[Call]]`. So it should only be one call either way.

Comment: In `iPad`, the performances of `apply` and `call` are the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess the cause might depend on which interpreter your are running the code on, but it seems that normal functions calls are faster because the interpreter can use Inline Cache to access the properties.

You can have a look [here](http://blog.mozilla.com/dmandelin/2011/06/16/know-your-engines-at-oreilly-velocity-2011/) for more information.

Comment: If you run this [test][1] you'll notice that .call is as fast as normal call, maybe because the interpreter as difficulties with the type inference when an array contains different type of values...

Comment: What do you mean by 'the interpreter can use Inline Cache to access the properties': what properties?

Comment: I meant the object properties. When you call obj.myProp in javascript, the interpreter need to loop through all properties in the object to check which one corresponds to "myProp". One of the possible optimization is to "remember" the index of this property in the object property list and directly jump to this property on the next function call.

Comment: the link to http://blog.mozilla.com/dmandelin/2011/06/16/know-your-engines-at-oreilly-velocity-2011/  is broken

Comment: yes, it seems to be broken now. I vaguely remember it pointed to a presentation of David Mandelin. From the link name, you can probably find the same material here: https://conferences.oreilly.com/velocity/velocity2011/public/schedule/detail/18087
(the pdf f this link is relevant for the answer anyway).