# Backbone triggerEvents

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am reading Backbone.js sourcecode for Events module and this code got me confused:

```js
var triggerEvents = function(events, args) {
  var ev, i = -1,
    l = events.length,
    a1 = args[0],
    a2 = args[1],
    a3 = args[2];
  switch (args.length) {
    case 0:
      while (++i < l)(ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx);
      return;
    case 1:
      while (++i < l)(ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx, a1);
      return;
    case 2:
      while (++i < l)(ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx, a1, a2);
      return;
    case 3:
      while (++i < l)(ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx, a1, a2, a3);
      return;
    default:
      while (++i < l)(ev = events[i]).callback.apply(ev.ctx, args);
      return;
  }
};
```

I'm wondering why should we determine `args.length`? Why not just write like that:

```js
var triggerEvents = function(events, args) {
    var ev, i = -1,
    while (++i < l)(ev = events[i]).callback.apply(ev.ctx, args);

};
```

So the main question is : Why should we determine `args.length`? Why not just use one `while (++i < l)(ev = events[i]).callback.apply(ev.ctx, args);` to replace all `call`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my "educated guess" (without knowing Backbone internals)
It seems that each `event` has a callback property, which is function to be called, when the `event` is triggered. Like `click` for example.

This callback function can take various number of arguments. Number of arguments is not known. That's where `args.length` kicks in. When you pass only single argument, it will call callback function with that single argument. If you call it with 2, it will pass 2 arguments, etc...

The reason why there is `callback.call()` and `callback.apply()` is because `.call()` passes the arguments to invoked function "one-by-one" whereas the `.apply()` passes all arguments as a single array.

Good explanation of difference between `.call()` and `.apply()` can be found in this article http://hangar.runway7.net/javascript/difference-call-apply

PS: Correct me if my guess about Backbone is wrong :)

**UPDATE**

There is comment in source code https://gist.github.com/badsyntax/4663217, just above the `triggerEvents` declaration. So that is your answer. You can try to find some perf tests :)

```
   // Optimized internal dispatch function for triggering events. Tries to
   // keep the usual cases speedy (most Backbone events have 3 arguments).
```

**UPDATE 2**

The reason for this optimization is that `.call()` can be faster than `.apply()`, because `.apply()` needs to construct the array as argument. (And calling .call() and .apply is almost always slower then calling the original method, simply because there is one more operation to perform)

Comment: Yes, `.call()` and  `.apply()` has diffrence between  the way of receiving arguments, but `args` is already a array, so I think in this situation utilize just one `.apply()` can  achieve the same effect, in other words, determine `args.length` and `.call()` don't make any sense , might be redundant, I guess.

Comment: @huachengzan Maybe you are right... can you test it please and provide link to results?

Comment: @huachengzan And this is the answer explaining the optimization http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184466/why-are-call-and-apply-slower-than-a-direct-function-call-in-javascript

Comment: This is a great help, I think I need this, thks again!